# How can I add a timeout parameter to this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, timeout, wait

I have the following JavaScript function.

```
function ready(interval, last_wait, el, callback) {
    if (jQuery(el).length) {
        console.log("Element ready: " + el)
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback(jQuery(el));
        }, last_wait);
    } else {
        console.log("Waiting element: " + el)
        setTimeout(function () {
            ready(interval, last_wait, el, callback);
        }, interval);
    }
};
```

It basically waits for a DOM element to exist. If it isn't, waits more `interval` milliseconds.
What I want is adding a `timeout` parameter. If the function wait `timeout` milliseconds in total and the DOM element still doesn't appear, then just do nothing, stop waiting and return. I can't make it work because of the recursive nature of the function. I also considered using a global variable, but it seems not the correct way to do it. Hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I updated my answer to stop after 3 attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

If you increase the stopAfter, the code will run to conclusion

```js
var tId, stopAfter = 3
const cb = el => el.html("Callback called");
function ready(interval, last_wait, el, callback) {
  if (stopAfter === 0) {
    clearInterval(tId);
    return;
  }
  if ($(el).length) {
    clearInterval(tId);
    console.log("Element ready: " + el)
    setTimeout(function() { callback($(el)); }, last_wait);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Waiting element: " + el)
  if (!tId) tId = setInterval(function() {
    stopAfter--;
    ready(interval, last_wait, el, callback);
  }, interval);
};

// testing the above
ready(1000,2000,"#div1",cb)
setTimeout(function() {     
  $("body").append(`<div id="div1">Div1</div>`) }
,5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @mplungjan, thanks for you answer. Your implement uses `stopAfter` as a counter and it will wait that many times of interval. What I want is a parameter that will be waited for that long time. They are not exactly the same.

Comment: How not? If you wait 3 times 5 sec is it 15 secs!

Comment: Uh, yes. Let me think about it. Thanks!